# How to retrieve images from mysql into ImageView in android

Tags: android, json

I am new to Android and I would appreciate any help if any one can please tell me how to retrieve am image from MySQL into ImageView in android. My database is in a free hosting website and I am using JSON to parse the data. Any links to appropriate website or tutorial can also help. Thanks in advance

Comment: It will be better if you give us details about how you are storing images? Are you using CDN to host images and then storing their links in mysql ? Have you written a REST webservice over mysql?